# Ajuda com json e adodb no PHP

Tags: php, json

boa tarde,

o seguinte código me retorna em json... mas é em pdo.. como seria em adodb?

```
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo '{"users": ' . json_encode($users) . '}';
```

edit:

tentei isto, mas não funciona:

```
if($db){
            $stmt = $db->Execute($sql);

            $retorno = array();
            while(!$stmt->EOF){
                $retorno[] = $stmt->fields;
                $stmt->MoveNext();
            }

            echo '{"retorno": ' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';    
        }
```

o que tentei fazr no código acima foi percorrer o recordset com os dados do select, inserindo estes dados no array.
e transformo o array em json..

me retorna o json vazio.. mas a consulta, pelo testo que fiz, me retorna dados

resultado do json:

```
{"retorno": }
```

resultado do print_r($retorno);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [VENDA] => [1] => 1 [PRODUTO] => 1  ) )
```

edit:

```
if($db){
            $stmt = $db->Execute($sql);

            $retorno = array();
            while($res = $stmt->GetArray()){
                $retorno[] = $res;
            }

            echo '{"retorno": ' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';    
        }
```

solução!

```
if($db){
            $stmt = $db->Execute($sql);
            $retorno = $stmt->GetArray();

            //var_dump($retorno);
            echo '{"retorno": ' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';    

            if( $jret = json_encode($retorno) ){ echo "nice"; } else{ echo "Fail"; }

        }
```

porém... os meus dados tem caracter especial como "ç" e o json não está aceitando isso.. ou seja.. não está aceitando utf-08.. quando removo os caracteres especiais o json funciona...

alguem sabe resolver isso?

Comment: cria um loop e faça a atribuição do array depois dele dê um `echo json_encode($dados);` se não me engano o ADOBD usa um méotodos `next()` e as props `EOF` ou `BOF`

Comment: Aparece algum erro? mais especificamente o quer seria 'não funciona'?

Comment: POderia colocar o resultado de: `print_r($retorno)` na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que vc percorra dois processos independentes.
Assim vc vai saber onde está o erro.

1. Crie sua array, independente de qual seja a maneira como vc se conecta ao banco de dados.
2. Transforme a sua array em JSON.

Depois de fazer o seu loop, vc vai criar uma array multi level `$arrTot`

```
$res = $db->Execute($sql);//Nota: Precisa adequar o código ao seu cenário

if ($res){

         while ($arr = $res->GetArray()) {

              $arrTot[]= $arr;  

         }
}
```

Depois transforme sua array em JSON:

```
$myJSON = json_encode(array($arrTot));
```

Comment: certo... editei e agora mostra este erro: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v1\index.php on line 20... editei minha pergunta

Comment: a informação q vc está buscando no banco de dados é muito grande? Geralmente eu esgoto a memória do php com uma query de 100.000 linhas (a depender do conteúdo). Se esse é o problema aumente a menória do php. O limite é 2gb. Se vc ultrapassar isso, vai ter que: 1-Mudar a estratégia ou 2-Mudar para o PHP 7 que tem memoria ilimitada, até o máximo disponível no sistema.

Comment: Veja esse post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874579/what-is-the-limit-in-size-of-a-php-variable-when-storing-string

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar em Array e depois usar json_encode.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * BLA BLA BLA...';

if (!($result = $db->Execute($sql))):
   throw new Exception($db->ErrorMsg());
endif;

var_dump($result->_array);  // veja primeiro se o seu array esta ok

//echo json_encode($result->_array); // mostre o json
```

Verifique também se o charset esta setado utf8

Comment: certo... onde seto o charset para utf8?

Comment: o banco é mysql? você pode fazer assim: `$db->SetCharSet('utf8');`

Comment: o banco é oracle 11g